# wordpress get term title on adding

Tags: wordpress

I may have the terminology mixed up so I hope you can follow.

I have a custom post type of 'Packages'
I have set the ability to create catagories called 'Add Package Type'

When I add a category I wish to insert a new page with the title of the new category only when it is in the 'Add Package Type'.

I cannot seem to get the category title with the following code, inside the $taxonomy I get 'Add Package Type' which is fine. But I wish to have the page as the same name as the title I have just entered.

Thanks

```
function custom_create_packages( $term_id, $tt_id, $taxonomy ){

    if($taxonomy == 'package type'){
        $new_page_title = $cat_title;
        $new_page_content = 'This is the page content';
        $new_page_template = ''; //ex. template-custom.php. Leave blank if you don't want a custom page template.
        //don't change the code bellow, unless you know what you're doing
        $page_check = get_page_by_title($new_page_title);
        $new_page = array(
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'post_title' => $new_page_title,
            'post_content' => $new_page_content,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_author' => 1,
        );
        if(!isset($page_check->ID)){
            $new_page_id = wp_insert_post($new_page);
            if(!empty($new_page_template)){
                update_post_meta($new_page_id, '_wp_page_template', $new_page_template);
            }
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'create_term', 'custom_create_packages', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, you'll have to retrieve the details of the term based on the `$term_id` parameter.  Something like:

```
function custom_create_packages( $term_id, $tt_id, $taxonomy ){

    if($taxonomy == 'package_type'){
        $term = get_term( $term_id, $taxonomy );
        $new_page_title = $term->name;
```

I don't know whether the taxonomy slug in your code ('package type') was just an example, but it should not contain spaces (see [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Parameters)).

It might be worth changing your action from `create_term` to `create_{taxonomy}` (e.g. `create_package_type`) to eliminate the need to check the taxonomy.  Note that `create_{taxonomy}` only has 2 parameters (`$term_id` and `$tt_id`), since the taxonomy is known.

I'm not certain, but it might be safer to call your function in the `created_{taxonomy}` hook (note the 'd'), which is called after the [`clean_term_cache`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/clean_term_cache) function is called (though given it's a new entry, that probably won't make a difference).